# Struggling to verify and validate user login using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, webforms

I'm trying to retrieve data from the user (login details) to compare it with data stored in a SQL server database, using WebForms and C# with WCF.

Heres my code: 
Service1.cs

```
 public int LoginMember(Member m)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        string sqlStr = "select Username, Password from Members where Username =@Username and PassWord=@Password";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataReader;


        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            return 1;
        }
            return 0;
```

Logincs.cs

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Member m = new Member();
        Service1Client service = new Service1Client();

        int result = service.LoginMember(m);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Shop sh = new Shop();
            sh.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login");
        }
```

I've added cmd Parameters as so:

```
 public int LoginMember(Member m)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        string sqlStr = "select Username, Password from Members where Username =@Username and PassWord=@Password";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", m.Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", m.Password);
        con.Open();

        cmd.Connection = con;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataReader;


        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But I am getting this error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYMPN.jpg)

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? 
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I am now getting this error: 
[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Gor.jpg)

Comment: It usually helps if you explain exactly what is not working, but I can see you do not set the SqlParameters on `cmd`. So there is at least one issue.

Comment: Hi, ive done as you told me, but I am getting an error (See Description)

Comment: That is unrelated to command parameters. The connection fails because no server can be found. I doubt your server instance is named "localhost".

Comment: Just realised that i didnt have the correct connection string. Now that ive fixed that im geting another error. Will update my description

Comment: You will have to debug the service (the LoginMember method). You are not getting any significant error details returned to the client. My guess at this point is the connection string is still wrong and the request times out while the database server is trying to be found.

Comment: I've fixed my error. Thanks for your help!